# Why is my min() function not working in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I was writing a mean-median-mode calculator in Python and am facing this error.

It is not returning the correct lowest value for the `new_arr` list in the `mode` function in this code

How can I correct it ?

Code :-

```
import collections
import statistics
from statistics import StatisticsError

elemag = int(input())
raw_arr = input()
arr = raw_arr.split(" ")

def mean(total, split_arr) :
    sum = 0
    for i in split_arr :
        sum += int(i)
    return (sum/total)
    
def median (total, split_arr) :
    
    new_arr = []
    for i in split_arr :
        new_arr.append(int(i))
    
    new_arr.sort()
    
    if total % 2 != 0 :
        mid_val_index = int(((total + 1)/2) - 1)
        return (new_arr[mid_val_index ])
        
    else:
        a = int(total/2)
        b = int(a - 1)
        
        c = int(new_arr[a])
        d = int(new_arr[b])
        return (c+d)/2
        
def mode(split_arr) :
    
    new_arr = []
    for i in split_arr :
        new_arr.append(int(i))

    try :
        return statistics.mode(new_arr)
    except StatisticsError as err :
        return min(new_arr)
        
print(mean(elemag, arr))
print(median(elemag, arr))
print(mode(arr))
```

Comment: Please include a sample input, expected output, and actual output so that we can better understand your question

Comment: Your life would be simpler if you converted the array to int at the beginning, rather than converting the elements in every function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Python 3.8. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode) says:

> *Changed in version 3.8*: Now handles multimodal datasets by returning the first mode encountered. Formerly, it raised `StatisticsError` when more than one mode was found.